# UserProfile id == None in form validation / save

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In a django view function to edit a user's profile, I'm seeing id==None at save time.  Neither the form nor the model makes explicit reference to UserProfile.id nor User.id. The UserProfile model has this typical line

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

and the form ends thus:

```
class Meta:
    """Provide an association between ModelForm and model."""
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('address', 'postal_code', 'city', 'country', 'date_of_birth')
```

All seems straight forward, and yet at save, I'm seeing an integrity violation.  The database is a testing db with two users, I'm pretty sure, from exhaustive inspection of the two entries, that the id fields are ok.

```
def edit_profile(request):
    """Edit/create a user's profile."""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data) # looks reasonable
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            # profile.user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            profile.user = request.user
            print('id=', profile.id) # Why is this None?
            # On save, we'll get Integrity error,
            # UNIQUE constraint failed: kernel_userprofile.user_id
            profile.save() # Integrity error
            print('form saved')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('kernel/profile'))
        # TODO(jeff@purple.com): Debug only, at most.
        print(form.errors)
    else:
        my_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        form = ProfileForm(instance=my_profile)

    return render(request, 'kernel/profilemod.html', {'form': form})
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`profile.id` field is set in the `profile.save()` method then `profile` created first time.

`IntegrityError` is raised because you trying to create new `UserProfile` instead of saving old one.  To solve this problem you should pass the `instance` parameter to `ProfileForm` constructor:

```
form = ProfileForm(request.POST,
                   instance=UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user))
```

**EDIT**: If you want edit **and** create profile in single view then read profile to edit using `first()` instead of `get()`:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
```

Comment: Thanks, and also for the tip about first(). Is edit and create unusual/ill-advised in the same function?

Comment: No, AFAIK edit and create in the same function is a common practice.